# EventListener variable fuera

Tags: javascript

Estoy consumiendo una api para el tiempo, el problema que tengo esque al detectar que Provincia escogen con addEventListener, no consigo pasar esa variable a otra funcion que tengo, ya que no llega. He probado con funciones globales y no soy capaz.

Aqui esta el problema

```
    listadoHtml.addEventListener('change',function(){
            window.provinciaSeleccionada = this.options[listadoHtml.selectedIndex].value;
        })
     console.log(window.provinciaSeleccionada)
```

Detecto que elemento escogen de un listado de opciones con las provincias, pero luego al setearlo en una variable y pasarlo fuera me llega que esa variable no esta definida. He probado con window al ser una variable global pero nada.

my html

```
<form>
        <select name="listado" id="listado" size="30" style="width: 300px;">
    </select>
</form>
```

codigo javascript

```
fetch('https://www.el-tiempo.net/api/json/v2/provincias')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => respuestaApiConDatos(data));

function respuestaApiConDatos(provincias) {

    const TodasLasProvincias = provincias.provincias
    const listadoHtml = document.getElementById("listado");

    const recorreArrayDeProvincias = (arr) => {
        for(let i=0; i<=arr.length-1; i++){
            let nombreProvincia = arr[i]['NOMBRE_PROVINCIA']
            let idProvincia = arr[i]['CODPROV']
            let option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = nombreProvincia;
            option.value = idProvincia;
            listadoHtml.add(option);
        }
    }
    recorreArrayDeProvincias(TodasLasProvincias)

    listadoHtml.addEventListener('change',function(){
            window.provinciaSeleccionada = this.options[listadoHtml.selectedIndex].value;
        })
     console.log(window.provinciaSeleccionada)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo único malo del código es el lugar donde se intenta leer la variable `provinciaSeleccionada`. Si se lee dentro del callback del evento ahí si tiene su valor configurado.

También es buena idea extraer el código del listener fuera de la función `respuestaApiConDatos` para dejarla más limpia.

```js
fetch('https://www.el-tiempo.net/api/json/v2/provincias')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => respuestaApiConDatos(data));

function respuestaApiConDatos(provincias) {
    const TodasLasProvincias = provincias.provincias
    const recorreArrayDeProvincias = (arr) => {
        for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
            let nombreProvincia = arr[i]['NOMBRE_PROVINCIA']
            let idProvincia = arr[i]['CODPROV']
            let option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = nombreProvincia;
            option.value = idProvincia;
            document.getElementById("listado").add(option);
        }
    }
    recorreArrayDeProvincias(TodasLasProvincias)
}

document.getElementById("listado").addEventListener('change', function () {
    window.provinciaSeleccionada = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(window.provinciaSeleccionada)
})
```

```html
<form>
        <select name="listado" id="listado" size="30" style="width: 300px;">
    </select>
</form>
```